# Disadvantage of using output deleted in sql query

Tags: sql-server

I am using output deleted.* in my query where I have millions of rows of data.

Is there any dis-advantage of using that ?

My query is :

```
DELETE from Table1
    OUTPUT deleted.* INTO Table2
    FROM Table4 MH
    inner join Table3 M
    on MH.id = M.Mid 
    where condition
```

It works perfectly fine. But does this lock the whole table ?
Is it a good approach ?

Answer (score 0):

You do have the added overhead of having to write the deleted rows to another table which will likely increase the amount of time the delete statement runs. But the locks held for the delete with the output clause versus without should be the same (just potentially a different duration). Verify it yourself with an extended events session in a non-production environment!

Comment: So, you saying it will still lock the entire table  when it is selecting and moving to other table ? Or would it lock the entire rows which it is selecting ?

Comment: That's not what I said. I said the locks between the two scenarios will be the same. So, if the non-output version takes row and page locks, so should the output version.